# Math Operator or tf.function - Which one should be used?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to implement a model, like this code I have given

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
base_model = VGG16(input_tensor=input_tensor,weights='imagenet',pooling=None, include_top=False)

x = base_model.output

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

x = tf.math.reduce_max(x,axis=0,keepdims=True)

x = Dense(512,activation='relu')(x)

output_1 = Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(x)

sagittal_model_abn = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output_1)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True
```

In this code, I have used `tf.math.reduce_max` to take the max values over the samples in the batch.

If the input shape to this `tf.math.reduce_max` is (16,6,6,512) then the output is (1,6,6,512)

Max-Pooling over the frames is the desired operation. The 16 frames that I am using has the same label, that is 16 frames constitute a single sample of the batch.

Max Pooling over `axis=0`, that is over the frames, is what needs to be done in my model.

This makes the batch size effectively 1. But since I cannot feed 5D tensor to the model, so I keep batch size as 1 and feed a 4D tensor to the model, as I am using 2D CNN.

Now, the dataset is a multilabel one. So I am using sigmoid activation in the last layer and binary cross-entropy loss.

But the problem that is occurring is that, all the predictions of the model are in the range 0.49-0.51 for all the samples, in every iterations.

```
[0.50119835 0.5004604  0.49988952]
[0.501212   0.5004502  0.49987414]
[0.50122344 0.5004629  0.49987343]
```

This shows that the model is not learning anything.

Is this because of the `tf.math.reduce_max` operator that I am using? Should using `@tf.function` for doing this same operation solve this issue?

I am using Adam optimizer with an initial LR of 0.00001.

The learning rate is small because I am fine-tuning the pre-trained VGG net.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe because you're using tf.math.reduce_max(). As you have mentioned that this method converts a tensor of shape(16, 6, 6, 512) => (1, 6, 6, 512).
As first dim in this shape is BatchSize (batchsize, imgShape1, imgshape2, numOfFilters)

A little summary of your model Would look like:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________

-------
-------
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Max (TensorFlowO [(1, 7, 7, 512)]          0         
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Gl (1, 512)                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (1, 512)                  262656    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (1, 3)                    1539      
=================================================================
Total params: 14,978,883
Trainable params: 14,978,883
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now as you know that a batch of 16(in your case) means there are 16 different images corresponds to different classes and after you apply <reduce_max> method this batch of 16 images squashes to one image. Now how you can classify 16 different images with one label. Your complete model should maitain the batch_size dim

```
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3)           *****
```

instead of

```
dense_1 (Dense)              (1, 3)               ****
```

You can apply reduce_max method to other dims (axis=1 or 2 or 3) but it is not advisable to use to on batch dim.

Hope you get it.

Comment: Actually I want to do that operation. My objective is to do max pooling over the frames. Those 16 frames belong to the same class, and my actual batch_size is 1. Since, I can't feed a 5D tensor so I take batch_size = 1 and feed a 4D tensor and taking max pooling over the frames is the desired operation here

Comment: if your actual batch_size is 1, than what's the point of doing reduce_max it'll give the same output.

Comment: In each sample of the batch, there are 16 frames. I want to do max pooling over the frames. 16 frames constitute a single sample

Comment: Apologies for not making it clear first. Please read my question. I have edited the question to make things clearer.